# How do I import two different data ranges in the same spreadsheet into R?

Tags: r, import, readxl

I would like to import the first and third tables and then join them together. It is noteworthy that the number of table rows is variable, so it is not possible to use a specific range to import.

Following is the content of excel data:

[image: spreadsheet_screenshot.norm]

Comment: Do these tables are stored in different excel files ? or a single one ?

Answer (score 0):

If all your tables are stored in a single excel file, you can use the `openxlsx` library.

I show you here a dummy example of excel file:
[image]

```r
library(openxlsx)
xl_file <- read.xlsx("../test_xl.xlsx")

> xl_file
  studyID rownames A  B  C   X6
1     ID1        A 1  1  1 <NA>
2     ID1        B 1 10  2 <NA>
3     ID1        C 1  3 10 <NA>
4    <NA> rownames D  E  F    G
5     ID2        D 2  7  6 <NA>
6     ID2        E 3  8  3 <NA>
7     ID2        F 5  5  2 <NA>
8     ID2        G 6  1  1 <NA>
```

Now to extract specific row, you can do:

```r
xl_file <- d[-4,1:5]

> xl_file
  studyID rownames A  B  C
1     ID1        A 1  1  1
2     ID1        B 1 10  2
3     ID1        C 1  3 10
5     ID2        D 2  7  6
6     ID2        E 3  8  3
7     ID2        F 5  5  2
8     ID2        G 6  1  1
```

So in your situation, if your excel file is called `Excel_file.xlsx` (and assuming that the file is in your working directory , you can do:

```r
library(openxlsx)
df <- read.xlsx("Excel_file.xlsx")
df <- df[,c(1:3,12:15)]
```

Hope it helps you to figure out the solution to your problem

Comment: openxls or openxlsx? You've written both

Comment: Oops. sorry for this mistake, thank you for noticing it !